How to get the current function name and file name and location (path) in python ? And how to get the calling function data as-well?
I've been searching for some useful code examples on this subject for creating a simple logger for my program.
Here are the things I've searched:

Getting the current function info (name, arguments, file name and path)
Getting the calling function into (name, file name and path, line number)

For some reason this information is scattered over many posts and locations and it would be nice to have them in one single location.

Here are all needed code examples for this purpose:
To get the file path do this:
import inspect
...
source_file_path = inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())

Or this:
source_file_path = __file__

Or this:
import sys
...
source_file_path = sys._getframe().f_code.co_filename

All of them return the same thing: The full path of the file in which the calling function resides:
/home/james/Documents/pythonExamples/example1.py

If you wan to get only the file name use 'Path' to help you:
from pathlib import Path
...
source_file_path = Path(source_file_path).name

To get the current function name do this:
import sys
...
source_func_name = sys._getframe().f_code.co_name

Or this:
import inspect
...
source_func_name = inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name

If you'd like to also get the arguments' list of current function do this:
import inspect
...
frame = inspect.currentframe()
argsList = inspect.getargvalues(frame).args

If you need the name of the calling function (one step back in the call-stack) - do this:
import sys
...
calling_function_name = sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_name

If you also want the calling function file name - do this:
calling_file_name = Path(sys._getframe().f_back.f_code.co_filename).name

And if you want the calling function line number in its file do this:
calling_function_line = sys._getframe().f_back.f_lineno

Hope this had helped.

import inspect
import sys
from pathlib import Path

class LoggerHelper:

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_file_path():
        return inspect.getfile(inspect.currentframe())

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_file_name():
        return Path(LoggerHelper.get_current_file_path()).name

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_function_name():
        return inspect.currentframe().f_code.co_name

    @staticmethod
    def get_current_function_args():
        frame = inspect.currentframe()
        return inspect.getargvalues(frame).args

    @staticmethod
    def get_calling_function_name():
        return sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_name

    @staticmethod
    def get_calling_file_path():
        return sys._getframe(2).f_code.co_filename

    @staticmethod
    def get_calling_file_name():
        return Path(LoggerHelper.get_calling_file_path()).name

    @staticmethod
    def get_calling_function_line_number():
        return sys._getframe(2).f_lineno

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    def sample_function():
        print("Current file path:", LoggerHelper.get_current_file_path())
        print("Current file name:", LoggerHelper.get_current_file_name())
        print("Current function name:", LoggerHelper.get_current_function_name())
        print("Current function arguments:", LoggerHelper.get_current_function_args())
        print("Calling function name:", LoggerHelper.get_calling_function_name())
        print("Calling file path:", LoggerHelper.get_calling_file_path())
        print("Calling file name:", LoggerHelper.get_calling_file_name())
        print("Calling function line number:", LoggerHelper.get_calling_function_line_number())

    def calling_function():
        sample_function()

    calling_function()


Nicely put. Well done !
